# How does one get an admin account on windows 8, with both accounts as Standard?

Tags: windows-8, administration, control-panel, non-admin

Alright, So I kind of 'derped' and made myself Standered accidentally, and now my whole computer's screwed up. Every time I try to access something? I have the 'Yes' and 'No' options, but 'Yes' is always unclickable, And because **there's no admin**. Is there any way to recover a admin account with standared account? Or just change myself back to admin?

Comment: Sure; enable the likely disabled administrator account plenty of tutorials on how to do that if you don't cureently have an admin account

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I restore lost Administrator rights?

> If there are no Administrator accounts on the system, you can boot to
>   Safe Mode to access the Built-in Administrator account.
>
> 1. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to display Settings.
> 2. Click the "Power Options" icon.
> 3. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the "Restart" option.
> 4. On the first screen, select "Troubleshoot".
> 5. On the next screen, select "Advanced Options".
> 6. On the next screen, select "Startup Settings". Click the "Restart" Button.
> 7. On the next screen, press <kbd>4</kbd>.
>
> The computer will start in Safe Mode.
>
> - Click the "Arrow" Icon.
> - Select the "Administrator" account.
>
> After Safe Mode starts, open "Control Panel" > "User Accounts".
>
> - Select "Manage another account" and select the account you wish to change to an Administrator account.
> - Select "Change Account Type".
> - Select the "Administrator" option and click the "Change account type" button.
>
> Exit Control Panel and Restart the computer.
>
> Log on with the account you changed to an Administrator account.

Source [Lost Admin rights in Windows 8 account. What to do?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/lost-admin-rights-in-windows-8-account-what-to-do/fb427b59-504f-4e9d-a187-692acaf79f82)